# Per-Model Bed Adhesion in Simplify3D

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion, simplify3d

I'm looking for a way to have different bed adhesion for different models in the same print. My question is similar to [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7907/setting-up-a-brim-raft-for-only-a-portion-of-the-overall-print), but I'm using Simplify3D.

I have an STL file that contains many different parts, and most of it prints fine except for a few small pieces which end up not sticking to the bed. I'd like to add bed adhesion for just the small parts while leaving the rest of the parts alone.

I started by splitting the STL file into smaller pieces with "Separate Connected Surfaces" then proceeded to make two separate print profiles, the first one for the majority of the parts with "Use Skirt/Brim" set to defaults (Skirt Layers 2, Skirt Offset from Part 4.00 mm, Skirt Outlines 2) and the second one for just the small parts with "Use Skirt/Brim" set to create adhesion (Skirt Layers 2, Skirt Offset from Part 0.00 mm, and Skirt Outlines 10).

I've then set the two processes to use their respective parts. When I go to print just the small parts alone I'm able to see the bed adhesion:

[image]

But if I attempt to print with all of the parts in the same print, the bed adhesion seems to drop down from 10 outlines to just 2 outlines but is still hugging the smaller parts. So it's like it took part of the settings ("Skirt Outlines") from one process and another part of the settings ("Skirt Offset from Part") from the other process to generate the final print.

[image]

What I'm looking for is how to have separate build adhesion for separate parts in the same print.